# Increasing performance when doing calculations with huge numbers (BigInteger)

Tags: java, performance, biginteger, factorial, catalan

I am a less experienced coder doing an exercise where I need to calculate the product of two [catalan sequences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO3dG.png) for every single `n`-value between `0` and `5000` and then summarize those products.

The code currently outputs the correct answer but takes between 2.9-3.3 seconds to run with an `n`-value of `5000`. My goal is to get the code to run in under 3 seconds every single time so I need to gain about half a second.

The largest number in the calculation (`10,000!`) is over `35,000` digits long so `int` or `long` can't be used for any of the heavier calculations, nor can I use any external libraries, which pretty much leaves me with `BigInteger`.

From testing I have discovered that the `for-loop` in `sum()`shown below is what takes the longest to complete by far (~85% of the run time) so that's where a performance increase is probably needed the most. Any tips on how to optimize it are appreciated.

```
// For all n-values
for (int k=0; k < n/2 + rest; k++) {
    result = result.add(catalan(k).multiply(catalan(n-k)));
}
```

Here is the entire code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialSum {

    static BigInteger[] bigInt;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int n = sc.nextInt();

            // Creates a new array and initializes the default values
            bigInt = new BigInteger[n*2+1];
            bigInt[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
            if (n > 0)
                bigInt[1] = BigInteger.ONE;

            calcFactorials(n);

            // Calculates and prints the results
            System.out.println(sum(n));
        } finally {
            sc.close();
        }
    }

    // Calculates and stores all the factorials up to and including the specified n-value
    private static void calcFactorials(int n) {
        for (int factor = 2; factor <= n*2; factor++) {
            bigInt[factor] = bigInt[factor-1].multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(factor));
        }
    }

    // Calculates the catalan number using the binomial coefficient for the
    // specified n-value
    private static BigInteger catalan(int n) {
        BigInteger binomial = bigInt[n*2].divide(bigInt[n].pow(2));
        BigInteger cn = binomial.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(n+1));
        return cn;
    }

    // Calculates the sum for the specified range 0-n
    private static BigInteger sum(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
            int rest = n % 2;

            // For all n-values
            for (int k=0; k < n/2 + rest; k++) {
                result = result.add(catalan(k).multiply(catalan(n-k)));
            }
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));

            // For even n-values
            if (rest == 0) {
                BigInteger lastNumber = catalan(n/2);
                result = result.add(lastNumber.pow(2));
            }
            return result;
        } else {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try running your sum in multiple threads, maybe run the even #'s in one and odd's in another, then sum those totals once both threads completed?

Comment: use pascal's triangle to compute the binomial coeffs

Comment: There is some potential for optimization. Instead of `x.pow(2)` rather use `x.multiply(x)`. That should be faster. `pow()` has quite some overhead. Also, use precalculated values, e.g. instead of `BigInteger.valueOf(2)`, precalculate it once and use that instead. That way it doesn't have to be allocated each time again. And you may want to store the results of the call `catalan(n)` too, so you don't have to calculate `catalan(n-k)` again (assuming it was already calculated). Note that I didn't try this yet, but I will.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `x.multiply(x)` already checks to see if it's being [multiplied by itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/math/BigInteger.java#1481), and uses specialized squaring algorithms. So that's likely to be faster (or, at least, just as fast; presumably that threshold is tuned). Also, `BigInteger.valueOf(2)` [will return a cached value](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/math/BigInteger.java#1093).

Comment: @AndyTurner: My point was that `x.multiply(x)` is very likely faster than `x.pow(2)`. I replaced `pow(2)`, but it didn't make a lot of difference in the overall performance, though(1-2% at most).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis oh, sorry, misread.

Comment: One optimization technique is to use longs where you can.  For instance, if you are multiplying two values and the largest is less than the square root of Long.MAX_VALUE, then use longs, don't convert to BigInteger first and multiple BigInteger, do the multiplication first and convert to BigInteger afterwards.  Same goes for addition and subtraction.  Only use BigInteger where necesary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to calculate the product of two catalan sequences for every
>   single n-value between 0 and 5000 and then summarize those products.

Well, this is exactly an alternative definition of a [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

C<sub>n+1</sub> = SUM<sub>i=0..n</sub> ( C<sub>i</sub> * C<sub>n-i</sub> )

So, what you basically need is to calculate C<sub>5001</sub>. To calculate it fast, you may use another recurrence relation:

C<sub>n+1</sub> = 2*(2n+1) / (n+2) * C<sub>n</sub>

Here is the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5000;

    BigInteger Cn = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        Cn = Cn.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(4 * i + 2)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(i + 2));
    }

    System.out.println(Cn);
}
```

Works less than 0.04 sec on my  laptop. Enjoy!

Comment: `2*(2n+1) / (n+2)` can be done purely in integer math, improving the performance even more

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No, it can't. Try to substitute n=2 :)

Comment: I don't understand. Why doesn't `(4*2 + 2)/(2+2)` work?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Because in integer arithmetics `(4*2 + 2)/(2+2) == 2`, but here you need to multiply C2 by `2.5` or to multiply by 10 and then divide by 4.

Comment: Oh wow, I never could have guessed that it was as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: @apangin got that. So I presume we can do that in floating-point math then use BigDecimal to calculate Cn?